# Code refactoring. Classes implementing same Interface

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have 4 `Classes` which Implement the same `Interface`. The Classes are e.g

`ABC`, `XYZ`, `LMN`,  now the Instance of class `LMN` may `belongTo` the instance of `XYZ` means can also be a Child Object. And If a Object is a child obect then It should not have all the methods available as independet object, Or there will be slight difference in it's functionality.

What is generally the best Pratice to handle such kind of sitution.

Comment: Are we talking about combining inheritance with composition here?

Comment: I would said that the best practice to handle such situation is to avoid them.

Comment: I don't think that this pattern is one you should completely avoid. However I would use it sparingly as normally it can be replaced with a simpler more intuitive pattern. However you will not be able to block some methods in the child, if you really need to use this pattern than in the methods you can have `if(!hasParent()){\* do something *\}`

Comment: Are you looking for the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may seem counter intuitive, but you might want to think about implementing a second interface `ChildInterface` that is the **parent** of `Interface`.  Put there the subset of methods that you want available to the children.

```
public interface ChildInterface{

    ...
}

public interface Interface extends ChildInterface{

    //add methods you don't want Children to have
}


public class XYZ implements Interface{
   ...
}
```

Then in your `Interface` interface or `XYZ` class, have a method

```
public ChildInterface getChild();
```

Since all your classes implement both interfaces, this will compile just fine and it will guarantee that the returned objects are restricted to only the methods in the `ChildInterface`.